# I have an error on decode a json on Swift 5

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing

I try to parse a json that my backend team make. But json kinda weird and I can't ask the backend team to change the json. so Here are the json:

```
{
"nama": [
    "Tigor Franky",
    "Achmad Fauzi",
    "Mario David Lela Muda",
    "Mily Anggreini Hutasuhut",
    "Arif Fahmi ST",
    "Satwika Narindra Dhipa",
    "Mujib Burahman",
    "Aresty Puji Harjanty",
    "Rio Jatmiko",
    "Halasson Sitanggang"
],
"u_id": [
    196,
    113,
    114,
    149,
    115,
    116,
    117,
    118,
    119,
    120
],
"totalakhir": [
    14.15,
    1.74,
    1.25,
    0.75,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
   ]
 }
```

so, this is new to me. How can I decode this?

so far I try this but theres an error that say

> "typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "nama", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))"

I try to make a struct like this:

```
struct HOF : Codable {
let nama : [Nama]
let u_id : [U_Id]
let totalakhir : [TotalAkhir]
}

struct Nama : Codable {
let namaa : String

enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case namaa = "nama"
   }
}

struct U_Id : Codable {
let u_idd : Int

enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case u_idd = "u_id"
   }
}
```

I know I'm wrong at making the struct but I just don't know how to make the struct.

Comment: The “nested structs” are wrong. Replace `let nama : [Nama]` by `let nama : [String]`, and similarly for the other properties of `struct HOF`.

Comment: Tell your backend team that it is more efficient to send dictionaries rather than multiple arrays even though the amount of sent data is a bit higher.

Comment: copy this json response to app.quicktype.io and it will automatically create the struct. try it once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **String** **Int** & **Double** are Codable types.
Thus an array of Codable types will work with Codable.

So there is no need to make types for **U_Id** or **Nama**

You can make your model as shown in the code below.
Codable will do the rest of the work for you.
You can run this sample in a playground and see the decoded output.

```swift
import Foundation

let json = """
{
"nama": [
    "Tigor Franky",
    "Achmad Fauzi",
    "Mario David Lela Muda",
    "Mily Anggreini Hutasuhut",
    "Arif Fahmi ST",
    "Satwika Narindra Dhipa",
    "Mujib Burahman",
    "Aresty Puji Harjanty",
    "Rio Jatmiko",
    "Halasson Sitanggang"
],
"u_id": [
    196,
    113,
    114,
    149,
    115,
    116,
    117,
    118,
    119,
    120
],
"totalakhir": [
    14.15,
    1.74,
    1.25,
    0.75,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
   ]
 }
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct DataModel: Codable {
    let nama: [String]
    let uId: [Int]
    let totalakhir: [Double]
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case nama
        case uId = "u_id"
        case totalakhir
    }
}

let em1 = try JSONDecoder().decode(DataModel.self, from:json)

print(em1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `struct` `HOF` to this and remove the other data types,

```
struct HOF : Codable {
    let nama : [String]
    let u_id : [Int]
    let totalakhir : [Decimal]
}
```

---

It seems lists are related to the same user so i would suggest asking your backend to change the json structure as below,

```
{
"hof": [
    {
      "nama": "Tigor Franky",
      "u_id": 196,
      "totalakhir": 14.15
    },
    {
      "nama": "Mily Anggreini Hutasuhut",
      "u_id": 113,
      "totalakhir": 1.74
    }
 ]
}
```

So, your data type will change to this,

```
struct HofUser : Codable {
    let nama : String
    let u_id : Int
    let totalakhir : Decimal
}

struct Response : Codable {
    let hof : [HofUser]
}
```

This will allow you to have only one list where each element has all the information related to a particular user.

Comment: Okayy thanks for the answer, i try to ask my backend to change that but no result until now, but thanks its works for me